# Passing routing from Express to Angular, Angular not picking up the redirect

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

In my Express file, I have:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);
});
```

Yeah, I know — the code above will cause a redirect loop but isn't this where Angular is supposed to come to the rescue like so:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'ui/books/index.html',
    controller: 'BooksController'
  })
  .otherwise({
    templateUrl: 'ui/x_partials/error.html'
  });
```

My intention is that, if an URL like `/non-existent-page` is provided, Express redirects it to Angular — `res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl)` — resulting in an URL like `#/non-existent-page`. Since this route hasn't been accommodated by my `$routeProvider`, I'm expecting `ng-view` to serve `templateUrl: 'ui/x_partials/error.html'`

But this approach isn't working! How do I get Angular to pick up the redirect from Express?

Please advise.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console? Can you create an example Plunkr or JSFiddle?

Comment: Never mind. I solved it like so: `app.all('*', function(req, res) {res.sendfile('./public/ui/index.html'); });`